# How can I download Magento 1.7 CE specifically?

Tags: downloader

I need this version specifically for an extension that only supports Magento 1.7.
When I download the '1.7 CE downloader' from the website, it runs and then downloads "the most up-to-date copy of the Magento software.". I don't want the latest.

Answer (score 4):

Go to http://www.magentocommerce.com/download and click on release archives and scroll down to the 1.7 section.

Answer (score 1):

(1) open url http://www.magentocommerce.com/download
(2)click on Released Archieve tab and download the version u want... 
note u should have a working magento account to download it.

Answer (score 0):

Just wget it:

```
wget http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.9.0.1/magento-1.9.0.1.tar.gz
```

For any other version:

```
wget http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/<version>/magento-<same_version>.tar.gz
```